# Apache HttpGet url encoding problem (plus sign, +)

Tags: java, android, url-encoding, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm sending a GET request with HttpClient but the `+` is not encoded.

---

1.
If I pass the `query` parameter string unencoded like this

```
URI uri = new URI(scheme, host, path, query, null);
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(uri);
```

Then the `+` sign is not encoded and it is received as a space on the server. The rest of the url is encoded fine.

2.If I encode the parameters in the `query` string like this

```
param = URLEncoder.encode(param,"UTF-8");
```

Then I get a bunch of weird symbols on the server, probably because the url has been encoded twice.

3.If I only replace the `+` with `%B2` like this

```
query = query.replaceAll("\\+","%B2");
```

Then `%B2` is encoded when the GET is executed by HttpClient

---

How can I properly encode Get parameters with Apache HttpClient and make sure the `+` is encoded as well?

Comment: Have you checked this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217070/how-do-i-add-query-parameters-to-a-getmethod-using-java-commons-httpclient), and its answers ?

Comment: That question refers to HttpClient 3, I'm using HttpClient 4 which is supported by Android.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, the solution was that instead of creating the URI like this

```
URI uri = new URI(scheme, host, path, query, null);
```

One should create it like this

```
URIUtils.createURI(scheme, host, -1, path, query, null);
```

The purpose of the URIUtils class is

> A collection of utilities for URIs, to workaround bugs within the
>   class

no comment........

Answer (score -1):

When you build the `query` string, use `URLEncoder.encode(paramValue, "UTF-8")` for each parameter value. Then when you send the request, use `URLDecoder.decode(paramValue, "UTF-8")` and the "weird symbols" will be decoded.

Comment: yes. maybe I misunderstood what you are looking for. If you encode the values, submit the request, then the server decodes them and can get back to the original values.