# Add query parameters to a GetMethod (using Java commons-httpclient)?

Tags: java, http, post, get, apache-httpclient-4.x

I followed [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217070/how-do-i-add-query-parameters-to-a-getmethod-using-java-commons-httpclient) to set parameter for the URL but it was giving error:

> The method `setQueryString(String)` in the type `HttpMethodBase` is not applicable for the arguments `(NameValuePair[])`

and

> Cannot instantiate the type `NameValuePair`.

I am not able to understand the actual problem. Could some one help me on this?

The code I have used from the above question

```
GetMethod method = new GetMethod("example.com/page";); 
method.setQueryString(new NameValuePair[] { 
    new NameValuePair("key", "value") 
});
```

Comment: Did u remove the superfluous semi-colon here `"example.com/page";`

Comment: Are you using httpclient 3.x or 4.x? The example you give is typical 3.x code, not 4.x.

Comment: Vikingsteve removed that semi-colon already when excuting the code

Comment: Great NilsH i am using 4.x.:). How to set parameters when using 4.x ?

Comment: @Anto sure? There is no GetMethod class in 4.x version. According to javadoc it is HttpGet

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In HttpClient 4.x, there is no `GetMethod` anymore. Instead there is `HttpGet`. Quoting an example from the [tutorial](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html#d5e43):

Query parameters in the url:

```
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(
 "http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=httpclient&btnG=Google+Search&aq=f&oq=");
```

Creating the query string programatically:

```
URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder();
builder.setScheme("http").setHost("www.google.com").setPath("/search")
    .setParameter("q", "httpclient")
    .setParameter("btnG", "Google Search")
    .setParameter("aq", "f")
    .setParameter("oq", "");
URI uri = builder.build();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(uri);
System.out.println(httpget.getURI());
```

Comment: I should also add that httpclient 4.x and httpclient 3.x have quite different APIs. Examples you find for httpclient 3.x will most likely not work with 4.x.

Comment: I am trying to use HTTPclient 4.2.5 with SalesForce REST API and it does not work - setting parameter results in an error page, while using "setQueryString" with 3.1 API results in JSON...
Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces can not be directly instantiated, you should instantiate classes that implements such Interfaces.

Try this:

```
NameValuePair[] params = new BasicNameValuePair[] {
        new BasicNameValuePair("param1", param1),
        new BasicNameValuePair("param2", param2),
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass query parameter within the the url.

```
String uri = "example.com/page?key=value";
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet method = new HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(method);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent()));
String content="", line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
     content = content + line;
}
System.out.print(content);
```

Comment: There is no GetMethod in the version i have used, Please have a look at the comments i have provided

Comment: I changed my answer according to your httpclient 4.x