# HttpClient parameters not being added to the executing method

Tags: java, http, servlets, get, httpclient

Sorry that it's potentially an easy answer but I can't find anything.

I currently have the method:

```
    public MediaSource getConvertedMediaServletCall(String format) throws HttpException, IOException{

    HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();

    GetMethod httpGet = new GetMethod(MEDIA_SERVER_URL);

    httpGet.getParams().setParameter("format", format);
    httpGet.getParams().setParameter("handler", "handle");

    try{
        int statusCode = httpclient.executeMethod(httpGet);

        byte[] responseBody = httpGet.getResponseBody();
```

Now I know this doing really do anything, this has to be worked on once I get the problem working. The problem is, I am create what I believe a http client, which executes the get method. Now the problem is when the code runs the *httpClient.executeMethod(httpGet);* the servlet doGet method is being executed, and I know this for a fact, but the parameters are never passed through from this executing method.

Anyhelpwould be appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone still wondering, although HttpClient gives you the methods for adding parameters, it won't work. Get parameters have to passed in the URL, and these parameters are being added to the body of the message, like a post request.

The workaround to this is discussed here: [How do I add query parameters to a GetMethod (using Java commons-httpclient)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217070/how-do-i-add-query-parameters-to-a-getmethod-using-java-commons-httpclient)