# Send and Receive an IList<int> with ASP.NET Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I need to send and receive an IList to my Web API:

API Method:

```
public IList<int> GetKeywordIdsFromIds([FromUri]List<int> ids)
{
     // this methods retuns null or an IList<int>
     return _iKeywordService.GetKeywordIdsFromIKeywordIds(ids);
}
```

Call method:

```
public List<int> GetKeywordIdsFromIds(IList<int> iKeywordIds)
{
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(API_BASE_URL);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

            return client.GetAsync(url + iKeywordIds).Result.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<int>>().Result;
        }
}
```

I get the error:

```
Exception:Thrown: "No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'List`1' from content with media type 'text/html'." (System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException)
```

EDIT:

I don't know if this helps but I get this from IIS Log File:

```
2014-03-31 16:11:31 127.0.0.1 GET /api/ikeyword/getkeywordidsfromids/System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32] - 80 - 127.0.0.1 - 404 0 2 1
```

EDIT2:

Default route:

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: See this post, how to add parameters to your code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217070/how-do-i-add-query-parameters-to-a-getmethod-using-java-commons-httpclient

Comment: Hi thanks but I don't see any example for an IList<int>

Comment: where do you put `List<int> ids` ? You leave it in the body or uri ?

Comment: @minhcat_vo Hi thanks, sorry but I don't understand your question

Comment: you leave your `List<int> ids` in your body message or in url ?

Comment: Are you saying the [FromUri] property in the API method? If so it's in URL

Comment: I think what he is asking is whether or not the list of IDs is part of the url (http://domain/api/controller/list/{list}) or if the list of ints is written to the body. It is better to put this data in the body than as part of the url, since you don't really know how many ids are going to be passed.

Comment: It's a call between a ConsoleApp and a MVC Web App so the information is passed as you can see in the question. I really don't know if it's what he is asking. Sorry...I think the problem is in the call "url + iKeywordIds" because if I try with url + "/1" it works fine

Comment: If you tried to call /1/2/3 . It would call your action.

Comment: I updated the question with the default api route

Comment: can you show your full uri ? I think the problem is `url + iKeywordIds`

Comment: Your API function is probably expecting a URL that that looks something like .../api/controllername?ids=1&ids=2&ids=3. You need to convert your List<int> on the client to the querystring that the function is expecting

Comment: @minhcat_vo it's "api/ikeyword/getkeywordidsfromids/"

Comment: @IanGilroy Hi thanks, and how can I do that? I tried "api/ikeyword/getkeywordidsfromids/iKeywordIds=1&iKeywordIds=2&iKeywordIds=3" but I still get the error: Exception:Thrown: "No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'List`1' from content with media type 'text/html'."

Comment: You write some code that parses your list and generates the required querystring. For example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17096201/build-query-string-for-system-net-httpclient-get

Comment: The parameter is called ids, not iKeywordIds. And I'm not convinced that the rest of the URL is correct either. Browse to the root of your site and use the built-in web api documentation to get the right URL.

Comment: @IanGilroy I think I found one of the reasons, I had "/" at the end of the url and I should have "?" but I'm still not able to pass the List as it is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To call the Web API action with a list of `int`s in the query string, do it like this...

```
/api/ikeyword/getkeywordidsfromids?ids=1&ids=3&ids=4
```

or

```
/api/ikeyword/getkeywordidsfromids?ids[]=1&ids[]=3&ids[]=4
```

From your IIS logs, it looks like you need to properly format the list in your console app and append it to the URL. Your calling code should look something like this...

```
var parameters = ids.Select(id => string.Format("ids={0}", id)).ToArray();
var url = string.Format("/api/ikeyword/getkeywordidsfromids?{0}", string.Join("&", parameters));
```

Comment: Hi thanks, and how to I process the value in the WebApi method?

Comment: `ids` should be a List of `int`s. You can pass it straight to `_iKeywordService.GetKeywordIdsFromIKeywordIds(ids)`...

Comment: It's working, please just correct your code so I can set your answer as correct: remove the "=" in the Format method: getkeywordidsfromids?{0} or else in the Api it will not receive the first value

Comment: It's me who Thank you!